# C# short-circuit evaluation without return value

Tags: c#

I have an EventHandler, it needs to call function with different values. If anyone returns true then stop going and return. That fits || short-circuit evaluation. What's the best way to write this?

Example:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // how to call foo(1), foo(3), foo(2)?
}
private bool foo(int i)
{
    return i == 3;
}
```

boring one without ||:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (foo(1)) { return; }
    if (foo(3)) { return; }
    foo(2);
}
```

Error:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foo(1) || foo(3) || foo(2);
}
```

Silly one with || and useless return:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (foo(1) || foo(3) || foo(2)) { return; }
}
```

Silly one with || and useless assignment:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var boo = foo(1) || foo(3) || foo(2);
}
```

Silly one with additional function:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bar();
}
private bool bar()
{
    return foo(1) || foo(3) || foo(2);
}
```

Complex one:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int i in new[] { 1, 3, 2 })
    {
        if (foo(i))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Linq one (harder to understand and maintain):

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new[] { 1, 3, 2 }).Any(i => foo(i));
}
```

My best choice is useless return. Do you have other choices?

Comment: Can you explain what "best" means in your situation? Performance? Maintainability? Something else?

Comment: new[] { 1, 3, 2 }.Any(foo);

Comment: IMO, the question as it stated doesn't suggest any requirements, and cannot not be answered. In addition to @atlaste questions: how much calls of `foo` must be chained? how often do you write this code? How `foo` argument values are produced (manually from code, user input, any external source)?

Comment: My "best" is...the conclution after consider of every espects... If I'm not in an EventHandler, I can change the return type from void to bool, then `return foo(1) || foo(3) || foo(2);` is my only answer, and I won't ask here. But now I can't change return type, but still love the short-circuit's simple and efficency. Wish to use || without those silly and extra things...

Comment: It happens only once, the parameter is actually an enum, and the order is not the sequence of enum. It's now hard coded, but later it may become a config. There are 4 now, but maybe more later. If it's a config, then it won't be || anymore, will be foreach or linq.

Comment: Sorry for asking a silly problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop seems to be the best choice, if you have a lot of different values.
if it's only a few values (no more then 3 or 4) you can go with the useless return, or something like this (that's basically the same):

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (foo(1) || foo(3) || foo(2)) { /* do nothing */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the `foreach` is the best just because it is more flexible (you can add more values if you ever need to).

Comment: How is your while loop look like?

Comment: @ChrisTorng the while loop will probably not work here as I understood when I read your question more thoroughly. I was thinking of something like `while(!foo(i)) i++;` but this only works if you are looping through a sequence e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: I know some of you will think of something like this, so change the values into 1, 3, 2...

Comment: I realized that after I posted my answer, that's why it was changed.

Answer (score 0):

if you have many handlers, you can use a `List<Func<bool>>` that holds your list of event handlers:

```
List<Func<bool>> handlers = new List<Func<bool>>() {
    () => foo(1),
    () => foo(2),
    () => foo(3)
};
foreach (var handler in handlers) {
    if (handler())
        return;
}
```

You probably also want to pass the event to `foo` but it's not clear what's its type, so just change the `Func` signature accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating it much more than it needs to be.  You're trying to write: "If calling `foo(1)` returns false, call `foo(3)`. If calling `foo(3)` returns false, call `foo(2)`" Why don't you just write exactly that?

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // adjust indentation/braces as you see fit
    if (!foo(1))
        if (!foo(3))
            foo(2);
}
```